# How to use of two times in one sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure

I have method A. This method has a limitation in high-dimension cases. This limitation leads method A to lose its flexibility in high-dimension.
Therefore, there is method B, which overcomes the limitation of method A.

I would like to say that:

*Method B overcomes the limitation (of method A) of losing the flexibility in high-diemension*

I feel that the grammar of my sentence is wrong. How could I present my sentence in a correct way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the grammar, but it is a bit awkward. I would probably say "Method B overcomes the limitation of method A, whereby flexibility is lost in high dimension"; but that's still somewhat awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You might try:

> Method A is limited by its loss of flexibility in a high dimension but Method B overcomes this limitation.
>
> Method B is not limited by a loss of flexibility in a high dimension like Method A is.
>
> Method B overcomes the loss of flexibility in a high dimension that limits Method A.

Comment: I should lose the **is** at the end of your second sentence - or replace **like** with **as**.